# Inscribing an ellipse in an irregular convex pentagon

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

Using the methods of projective geometry, identify the unique ellipse that is inscribed in a given convex pentagon.

Suppose the vertices of the pentagon are: $(1, 0), (4, 2), (3, 6), (-1, 5), (-1, 1)$.  Find the equation of the unique inscribed ellipse that is tangent to all five sides of this convex pentagon.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what this means.  I would appreciate if you could expand this comment and elaborate on it, if you have the time, and make it an answer, for me, and for the interest of this particular problem.

Comment: The way I solved this problem was the direct approach, where I specified the unknown ellipse using it equation $(r - C)^T Q (r - C) = 1 $, then iteratively found $Q$ and $C$ using the constraints of tangency on the five sides of the pentagon.

Comment: Anoter way would be to use Brianchon's theorem like in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330822/305862).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's easier to find the dual conic first.**

Rewrite every tangents in the form:

$$X_i x+Y_i y+1=0$$

Then $(X_i,Y_i)$ are the five points defining the dual conic:

$$
\begin{align}
  0 &= \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    X^2 & XY & Y^2 & X & Y & 1 \\
    X_1^2 & X_1 Y_1 & Y_1^2 & X_1 & Y_1 & 1 \\
    \vdots & & & & & \vdots \\
    X_5^2 & X_5 Y_5 & Y_5^2 & X_5 & Y_5 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix} \\ \\
  &= AX^2+2HXY+BY^2+2GX+2FY+C \\
\end{align}$$

The required ellipse is

$$
\begin{align}
  0 &= -\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & x & y & 1 \\
    x & A & H & G \\
    y & H & B & F \\
    1 & G & F & C \\
  \end{pmatrix} \\ \\
  &= ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c
\end{align}$$

Note that $a$ is the co-factor of entry $A$ of the $3\times 3$ block matrix, etc.

For the vertical tangent, try to let $Y_i=N$ and only the terms with highest order in $N$ survive.

See also the case of quadrilateral [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382743/ellipse-inscribed-in-an-irregular-quadrilateral/4383277#4383277).

Comment: How is any pentagon the image of a regular pentagon ? @JeanMarie

Answer (score 4):

Idea - see picture. Find five points - lines with points intersection of diagonals and $A,B,C,D,E$ give tangent points.
Answer:
$$\frac{-435}{764}x^2+\frac{75}{382}xy-\frac{3481}{8404}y^2+\frac{165}{191} x+\frac{421}{191}y-1=0$$

[image]

Solution with Python

```
from math import isclose
from sympy import *

a,b,c,d,h=symbols('a,b,c,d,h')

A=Point(1,0)
B=Point(4,2)
C=Point(3,6)
D=Point(-1,5)
E=Point(-1,1)

print(A,B,C,D,E)
def PE(A,B,C,D,E):
   AD = Line(A, D) 
   EB = Line(E, B)
   H = EB.intersection(AD)[0]
   CH = Line(C, H)
   EA = Line(E, A)
   J = CH.intersection(EA)[0]
   return(J)

def eq_ellipse(x,y):
  return(x*x*a+x*y*b+y*y*c+d*x+h*y-1)

Q1=PE(A,B,C,D,E)
Q2=PE(B,C,D,E,A)
Q3=PE(C,D,E,A,B)
Q4=PE(D,E,A,B,C)
Q5=PE(E,A,B,C,D)
print(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)
(x1,y1)=Q1
(x2,y2)=Q2
(x3,y3)=Q3
(x4,y4)=Q4
(x5,y5)=Q5
print(x1*1.,y1*1.)
print(x2*1.,y2*1.)
print(x3*1.,y3*1.)
print(x4*1.,y4*1.)
print(x5*1.,y5*1.)

#equation= x1*x1*a+x1*y1*b+c*y1*y1+d*x1+h*y1=1
eq1= eq_ellipse(x1,y1)
eq2= eq_ellipse(x2,y2)
eq3= eq_ellipse(x3,y3)
eq4= eq_ellipse(x4,y4)
eq5= eq_ellipse(x5,y5)

answ=solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5],(a,b,c,d,h))
print(answ)
print('a=', a.subs(answ).n())
print('b=', b.subs(answ).n())
print('c=', c.subs(answ).n())
print('d=', d.subs(answ).n())
print('h=', h.subs(answ).n())

major=-sqrt(2*(a*h*h+c*d*d-b*d*h-(b*b-4*a*c))*(a+c+sqrt((a-c)**2+b*b)))/(b*b-4*a*c)
minor=-sqrt(2*(a*h*h+c*d*d-b*d*h-(b*b-4*a*c))*(a+c-sqrt((a-c)**2+b*b)))/(b*b-4*a*c)

major=major.subs(answ)
minor=minor.subs(answ)
print('major=', major)
print('minor=', minor)

print(major.n())
print(minor.n())

print(latex(major))
print(latex(minor))


Point2D(1, 0) Point2D(4, 2) Point2D(3, 6) Point2D(-1, 5) Point2D(-1, 1)
Point2D(1/23, 11/23) Point2D(64/31, 22/31) Point2D(128/37, 154/37) Point2D(337/271, 1507/271) Point2D(-1, 143/59)
0.0434782608695652 0.478260869565217
2.06451612903226 0.709677419354839
3.45945945945946 4.16216216216216
1.24354243542435 5.56088560885609
-1.00000000000000 2.42372881355932
{a: -435/764, b: 75/382, c: -3481/8404, d: 165/191, h: 421/191}
a= -0.569371727748691
b= 0.196335078534031
c= -0.414207520228463
d= 0.863874345549738
h= 2.20418848167539
major= 401291*sqrt(806022722925/161034466681 - 195021225*sqrt(1105729)/161034466681)/363090
minor= 401291*sqrt(195021225*sqrt(1105729)/161034466681 + 806022722925/161034466681)/363090
2.13503582316532
2.76937406008801
\frac{401291 \sqrt{\frac{806022722925}{161034466681} - \frac{195021225 \sqrt{1105729}}{161034466681}}}{363090}
\frac{401291 \sqrt{\frac{195021225 \sqrt{1105729}}{161034466681} + \frac{806022722925}{161034466681}}}{363090}
```

Comment: What justifies this construction ?

Comment: @JeanMarie [Brianchon'sTheorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem). If $ABCDE$ is a convex pentagon and $F$ is the point of tangency of the inscribed ellipse on $\overline{AE}$, then $ABCDEF$ acts as a hexagon to which the theorem is applied. Thereby $F$ must be collinear with $C$ and the intersection of $\overline{AD}$ with $\overline{BE}$. The entire diagram is obtained by this method with cyclically permuting the labels $A$ through $E$.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Thank you very much. It's very clear now !